# Getting "Internal Server Error" for friendly urls

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm using Yii2 advance template, and when i enable friendly url on my EC2 ubuntu 20 i get `Internal Server Error`

It works fine on my localhost on windows 10.

in my `/var/www/html/frontend/` directory i have this in my `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
    
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
    RewriteRule ^admin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^admin/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^admin/js/(.*)$ backend/web/js/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/web/(assets|js|css|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
    RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css|js|images)
    RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend/web/js/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ frontend/web/images/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
</IfModule>
```

and in this folder `/var/www/html/frontend/web/` i have this in my `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and i have this on my server in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@blabla.com
        ServerName blabla.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/frontend/web
        ServerAlias blabla.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/html/frontend/web>
                Options FollowSymlinks
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: As this is your ec2 instance and not some shared host, you should have access to the Apache error log for the error msg

Comment: @TobiasK. forgot about that. thanks. i'm getting `/var/www/html/frontend/web/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration` but i already enabled `a2enmod rewrite` and restarted apache too

Comment: @TobiasK. thanks! got it working. missed the `sudo` infront of  `a2enmod rewrite` :\